# springboot app. failing "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a springboot application with springcloud dependency,

I have added the following dependency and application started to fail:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>


<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Error Message::

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata

without this dependency application works, I want to use the eureka server and register my client code as eureka client. Any thoughts are welcome. Tks

Comment: What version of spring boot are you using? Greenwich only works with boot 2.1.x

Comment: 2.5.1 - is my springboot version

Answer (score 2):

Using below spring cloud version solved the problem.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

I refered this: https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/3-1/common/client-dependencies.html

tks to @spencergibb for the hint.